# How to filter data from firebase using array of objects?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from firebase with a matching array of objects. But I don't know why it is not working. Please help me to resolve this small issue.

Currently, i am filtering data using creator.
[image]

But I want to filter using an array of objects located in the team object.
[image]

Currently, I am doing it like the below. but I want to change the condition. Please guide me

```
this.firestore.collection('projects', ref => ref.where('creator', '==', this.userId)).snapshotChanges()
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish or what isn't working the way you expect.  Your code is currently filtering on a field called "creator", which we can't see at all in your screenshot.  It shows a field called team which is an array of objects. Please edit the question to be more clear.  It might help to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter when a certain item that you have in your code exists in an array, you can use the [`array-contains` operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership).

That won't work in your case however, since you seem to only have part of the array item, and Firestore's `array-contains` require that you specify the entire contents of the array item.

So without modifying your data structure, the query isn't possible.

---

A common workaround is to create an *additional* field where you just hold the values that you want to query on. So in your case that'd be an array field with the UIDs, like:

```
creator_uids: [""Zlm...ord2", "0fBuf...hv2"]
```

And then you can use a query like this:

```
ref.where('creator_uids', 'array-contains', this.userId)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not filter array objects from the firebase as firebase does not  allow that.
The closest  possibility you can achieve is get the records and find it through for loop.

An algorithm:
if(data matches search.id)